# How to use AndroidManifest Merger

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, adt

I recently discovered the new ADT feature :

in the project.properties file i added the line:

> manifestmerger.enabled=true

I have an Android library project and 3 Android Application projects deriving from it, what can be declared once in the lib manifest, and what (obviously that are used on the all apps and the lib) must be declared on the apps manifests.

Is there a tutorial on how to work with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found google's official documentation here:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

Update [2014-04-30]:
As of today, google released android gradle tools 0.10. This introduces a new manifest merger. It is off by default but will replace the old. It seems the URL I provided above replaced the xml based merger docs.